# Scrapy. Proper way to implement request to another site while parsing item

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

In my scrapy spider, when parsing the page with the item, I need to retrieve additional information from the **other site**.
I can implement it by using requests and update the item with the response within parse method of the spider.
I'm looking for the better way to implement it, without using additional library.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: You can have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-inline-requests (you may also need to update your `allowed_domains` attribute).

Comment: Thank you @paultrmbrth , interesting approach.

Comment: @rojeeer , I'm using simple spider just like in examples, but wanted to make additional call. Seems that I need to switch to post processing of scrapped data and then make a request.

Comment: I remember that Scrapy [request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) provides keywords `meta` to store associated information with this request, and when you get the returned response, you can fetch the corresponding `meta` you set before. Through this way, you can add information you have extracted to the following request. If your item is not too complex, I believe this is a good solution.